# error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, gcc, cygwin, mingw-w64

When trying to build I get this error:

```
$ make CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
  CC    aes.c
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `PATH` to `/usr/bin` instead of `/bin`

> There is a known caveat where calling the compiler directly as
>   `/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` will fail, use
>   `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` instead and make sure that your `PATH`
>   variable has `/usr/bin` before `/bin`.

[mingw-w64.sourceforge.net](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net)

This is caused by a mounting problem. On linux you have `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, no big deal. On Cygwin you have `C:\cygwin\bin`. Then mount points are set like this.

```
C:\cygwin\bin on /usr/bin
C:\cygwin on /
```

So technically you could represent `C:\cygwin\bin` with `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, although as stated above the former will not work.

Comment: By any chance do you have any idea why this is an issue?

Comment: I'm curious what the underlying problem is when `/bin` is in the path before `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss `g++` for `mingw`.

Try this:

```
sudo apt install g++-mingw-w64-i686
```

After that either `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` or `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` will compile your sources.