# Unable to build AOSP rom on Mac os High Sierra

Tags: android, macos, gcc, linux-kernel, android-source

I'm trying to build an Android 10 rom on Mac OS High Sierra (10.13.6) but even after establishing the build enviroment as it is stated here https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing I am getting the following output

```
including vendor/aosp/vendorsetup.sh
ccache found and CCACHE_EXEC has been set to : /usr/local/bin/ccache
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
Trying dependencies-only mode on a non-existing device tree?
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
CUSTOM_VERSION=PixelExperience_evert-10.0-20200721-2149-UNOFFICIAL
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_evert
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-10.13.6
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=QQ3A.200705.002
OUT_DIR=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=vendor/google-customization/apex/apex_images vendor/motorola/evert device/motorola/evert vendor/motorola/sdm660-common device/motorola/sdm660-common hardware/qcom-caf/msm8998 hardware/qcom-caf/common/fwk-detect
============================================
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
CUSTOM_VERSION=PixelExperience_evert-10.0-20200721-2149-UNOFFICIAL
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_evert
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-10.13.6
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=QQ3A.200705.002
OUT_DIR=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=vendor/google-customization/apex/apex_images vendor/motorola/evert device/motorola/evert vendor/motorola/sdm660-common device/motorola/sdm660-common hardware/qcom-caf/msm8998 hardware/qcom-caf/common/fwk-detect
============================================
Environment variable BUILD_NUMBER was modified (dfd121530b => dd64c2817e), regenerating...
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
Environment variable BUILD_NUMBER was modified (dfd121530b => dd64c2817e), regenerating...
[100% 2/2] initializing build system ...
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
[  0% 4/461] including art/Android.mk ...
art/build/Android.common.mk:51: warning: unsupported HOST_ARCH=x86_64
[ 99% 460/461] finishing build rules ...
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/platform_test_list.mk: warning: platform_tests: Unknown installed file for module 'LauncherRotationStressTest' 
[100% 461/461] writing build rules ...
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/etc/init/android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service.rc'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:525: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/etc/init/android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service.rc'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/lib64/com.fingerprints.extension@1.0.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:510: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/lib64/com.fingerprints.extension@1.0.so'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/system/lib/libbtconfigstore.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:510: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/system/lib/libbtconfigstore.so'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/system/lib64/libbtconfigstore.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:510: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/system/lib64/libbtconfigstore.so'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/lib/vendor.qti.hardware.btconfigstore@1.0.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:510: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/lib/vendor.qti.hardware.btconfigstore@1.0.so'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/lib64/libsensorndkbridge.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:510: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/lib64/libsensorndkbridge.so'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/lib64/vendor.qti.hardware.btconfigstore@1.0.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:510: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/vendor/lib64/vendor.qti.hardware.btconfigstore@1.0.so'
/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/CONFIG/kati_packaging/dist.mk was modified, regenerating...
[  0% 471/82618] Building Kernel Config
FAILED: /Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/.config
/bin/bash -c "(PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r353983d/bin:\$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r353983d/lib64:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-/bin:\$PATH PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/darwin-x86/bin:\$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/darwin-x86/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PERL5LIB=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/common/perl-base /Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/build-tools/darwin-x86/bin/make  -j4 CFLAGS_MODULE=\"-fno-pic\" HOSTCFLAGS=\"-I/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/external/elfutils/libelf -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\" HOSTCC=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gcc HOSTCXX=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-g++ -C kernel/motorola/msm8998 O=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=\"/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-\" CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=\"/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androidkernel-\" CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- CC=\"/usr/local/bin/ccache clang\"       VARIANT_DEFCONFIG= SELINUX_DEFCONFIG= lineageos_evert_defconfig ) && (if [ ! -z \"\" ]; then             echo \"Overriding kernel config with ''\";      echo  >> /Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/.config;             PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r353983d/bin:\$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r353983d/lib64:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-/bin:\$PATH PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/darwin-x86/bin:\$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/darwin-x86/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PERL5LIB=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/common/perl-base /Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/build-tools/darwin-x86/bin/make  -j4 CFLAGS_MODULE=\"-fno-pic\" HOSTCFLAGS=\"-I/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/external/elfutils/libelf -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\" HOSTCC=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gcc HOSTCXX=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-g++ -C kernel/motorola/msm8998 O=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=\"/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-\" CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=\"/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androidkernel-\" CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- CC=\"/usr/local/bin/ccache clang\"       oldconfig;         fi ) && (PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r353983d/bin:\$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r353983d/lib64:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-/bin:\$PATH PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/darwin-x86/bin:\$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/darwin-x86/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PERL5LIB=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/common/perl-base /Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/build-tools/darwin-x86/bin/make  -j4 CFLAGS_MODULE=\"-fno-pic\" HOSTCFLAGS=\"-I/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/external/elfutils/libelf -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\" HOSTCC=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gcc HOSTCXX=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-g++ -C kernel/motorola/msm8998 O=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=\"/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-\" CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=\"/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androidkernel-\" CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- CC=\"/usr/local/bin/ccache clang\"       savedefconfig ) && (if [ ! -z \"\" ]; then             echo \"Using additional config ''\";            kernel/motorola/msm8998/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh -m -O /Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ /Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/.config kernel/motorola/msm8998/arch/arm64/configs/;             PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r353983d/bin:\$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r353983d/lib64:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-/bin:\$PATH PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/darwin-x86/bin:\$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/darwin-x86/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PERL5LIB=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/tools-custom/common/perl-base /Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/build-tools/darwin-x86/bin/make  -j4 CFLAGS_MODULE=\"-fno-pic\" HOSTCFLAGS=\"-I/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/external/elfutils/libelf -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\" HOSTCC=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gcc HOSTCXX=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-g++ -C kernel/motorola/msm8998 O=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=\"/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-\" CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=\"/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androidkernel-\" CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- CC=\"/usr/local/bin/ccache clang\"       KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG=/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/.config alldefconfig;         fi )"
make: Entering directory '/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/kernel/motorola/msm8998'
make[1]: Entering directory '/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ'
  GEN     ./Makefile
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
couldn't understand kern.osversion `17.7.0'
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:91: scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/kernel/motorola/msm8998/Makefile:446: scripts_basic] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/out/target/product/evert/obj/KERNEL_OBJ'
make: *** [Makefile:152: sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/Volumes/Disk2/roms/peplus/kernel/motorola/msm8998'
19:02:32 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (12:52 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I am working on an external drive formatted on disk sensitive APFS.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274468/error-trying-to-exec-as-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Sorry, noob here, this means I should put in my .bash_profile export PATH="/usr/bin" ? I have several lines like that with different paths for the compiling

Comment: According to it, add /usr/bin BEFORE bin.
So try something like this:  export PATH="/usr/bin/:$PATH"

Comment: Added it but it's still the same, I also noticed that the link you provided was for cygwin and I'm on mac os

Comment: If you have difficulties in setting up AOSP build environment, you can try to run your build in a docker container. Reference : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/tools/docker

Comment: Well, I went for it however docker file system share has a huge memory leak and compiling with no memory is pointless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what I did that made compiling go on was to copy `as` (and afterwards `ls` as well because it was causing a similar issue)from /usr/bin/ to prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/i686-apple-darwin-4.2.1/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ replacing the `as` and `ls` that when I tried executing it said that the shortcut was being directed to nowhere (or something like that, I'm translating from spanish)